# Iterate a n-array and store values in variables

Tags: python, numpy

I have a n-array like this:

```
[[167. 207. 277. 480.   1.]

 [294. 210. 385. 471.   2.]

 [448. 212. 532. 474.   0.]]
```

I want to store there row values in 4 variables say a,b,c,d as I want them to write in a file row by row by iterating over the n-array, as I have a lot of these arrays and want them to store in a file.

Comment: I don't see how assigning rows to variables is related to writing the data to files

Comment: Your question is a bit ambiguous. Can you provide the expected output what you want to achieve? Also a code snippet of what you have tried so far?

Comment: i want to store the first row values in these variables in a,b,c,d and then iterate next row and then again store next values.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
n_array = [[1,2,3,4],
       [5,6,7,8],
       [9,10,11,12]]

for a, b, c, d in n_array:
    print ("a = ", a)
    print ("b = ", b)
    print ("c = ", c)
    print ("d = ", d)
```

Comment: kind off this but does it stores 1,2,3,4 in a,b,c,d? and then 5,6,7,8 in next iteration?

Comment: Yes it does. Try it!